# How do I access my website using the domain name instead of localhost?

Tags: dns, localhost

To be more specific, I have a website called koyn. Here's the domain http://koyn.net . The website is hosted on my computer for testing purposes. I set up port forwarding and made the domain name point to my computer. Everything works fine because when I give the link out to people they can see my website fine, but here's my problem. When I visit my own visit on my computer on my network it directs me to my router settings. I have to type

```
http://localhost
```

in my address bar to access my website. I don't want to type localhost I want to access my website with koyn.net like everyone else. How can I do this? Thanks in advance :D!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on windows box you need to edit the hosts file, so when ever you type koyn.net it will reroute to localhost.

Comment: Never mind i got it. Thanks! For anyone wondering what the answer was like kiranvj said you need to go to your hosts file on windows (the directory should be C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) and then add this one line of code 

127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com

Comment: Yes that will work fine, I posted the answer from mobile, so just typed only point, thought a google search with "how do I edit hosts files in windows" with get more info. Anyway glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have removed your port forwardig. Have you tried cleaning out your browser cache? Another option, assuming you are on a Windows machine is to flush your DNS with the following command:

ipconfig /flushdns

Answer (score 0):

Editing Your Hosts File

Windows default location of host file: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Open it by **notepad** as **administrator**

All operating systems will have a hosts file like my example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
123.45.67.89 www.example.com
#98.76.54.32 www.anotherexample.com
```

More: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7e2MmyPvnhs

after save and flush your **dns** by command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```